# How summing DataFrame column values over chunks defined by a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am sorry for the possibly newbie question.

Having a list of IDs, I would like to use them to group rows of a DataFrame and sum these groups of rows.

Taking as example data the following DataFrame and ID list for instance:

```py
inp = pd.DataFrame({'amount': [0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 1.2, 0.9, 0.5],
                    'id':     [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 22, 26]})
ids = [10, 14, 26]
```

I need a function that will return the sum of values in `amount` for the group of rows being in-between `ids[i]` and `ids[i+1]`, including `ids[i]`, and excluding `ids[i+1]`.

With provided example, this would result in DataFrame (keeping the column `ids`).

```py
resu = pd.DataFrame({ 'ids' = [10, 14, 26],
                      'summed_amount' = [0.2 + 0.5,
                                         0.8 + 0.9 + 1.2 + 0.9,
                                         0.5]
                    }]
```

Please, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` on `isin` to identify the blocks:

```
blocks = inp['id'].isin(ids).cumsum()

inp.groupby(blocks, as_index=False).agg({'id':'first', 'amount':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
   id  amount
0  10     0.7
1  14     3.8
2  26     0.5
```

Comment: Hi @Quand_Hoang, thank you very much for this very concise answer. Please, what `isin().cumsum()` does? Do you have a link to related documentation? I can only find cumsum spec. for DataFrame. But for a DataFrame mask here, I don't find it. I don't understand what it does. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Quand_Hoang, ok, sorry, I played with these commands and I think I understand. Each time a 'True' value is found in the pd.Series obtained with `isin()`, it increments a counter with `cumsum()`, giving each block a distinct label. Very smart! Thanks a lot!